# Find an equation of the parabola with zeros $0$ and $6$ and a minimum value of $-9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The zeros of a quadratic relation are $0$ and $6$. The relation has a minimum value of $-9$. Find an equation of the parabola.

Hello, I've tried to come up with a solution to the exercise but it's complicated. I don't really know if it's right or not.

The quadratic equation is: $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Then we have $3$ points: $(0,0),(0,6),(x,-9)$
\begin{align*}   
c & = 0\\
36a+6b+c & = 0\\
-b^2+4ac+36a & = 0
\end{align*}
The $y$-coordinate of the vertex is $-\Delta/4a$.

Then we will use $c$ and the substitution method to solve $a,b,c$. Is that right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If by a "quadratic relation" you mean $y=ax^2+bx+c,$ then you have $y = a(x-0)(x-6),$ so that $y=0$ if $x$ is either $0$ or $6.$ Then you need to figure out which value of $a$ will make the minimum $y$-value $-9.$ Symmetry shows that if the $x$-intercepts are $0$ and $6$ then the minimum $y$-value occurs when $x$ is halfway between $0$ and $6$. So $y = a(3-0)(3-6) = -9,$ so what is $a$?

Comment: oh your way is much easier to understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: @KhanhNguyen : I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the roots are $0$ and $6$, the quadratic equation will have the form

$$y=f (x)=a (x-0)(x-6)=a (x^2-6x) $$

the minimum is attained at $c $ such that
$$f'(c)=a (2c-6)=0$$
thus $c=3$ and
$$f (3)=-9a=-9$$
which gives $a=1$

finally the desired equation is
$$y=x (x-6) $$
$$=(x-3)^2-9\ge -9$$